# Counter returns unexpected value

Tags: counter

This my cpp code and I am confused because cnt returns x = 0 !

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int i;
int cnt () {
  for (i = 0; i<15; i++) {
    return i;
  }
}
int main () {
  int x;
  x = cnt();
  cout << x << endl;
}```
````

Comment: As soon as you call function `cnt()` it retuns 0 at the first iteration of the loop. The loop is interrupted, and the main function assigns the returned value, which is 0, to the x variable, and prints it. This is a very basic programming concept, keep doing more tutorials, and you will understand it better with time.

Comment: You might want to move the return statement outside of `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` function stops every other instruction in the function from being executed and returns the chosen value to the function which called it. Your loop is executed just once.